# Tokenize sentences based on dictionary

Tags: python, nlp

I have few key words say - RAM, Speaker, Brand, Display etc. I have made a dictionary of all possible values these keys can have. Like - RAM can have 12, 12gb, 12GB; Display can have 12inch, 12", 12 inch.

I am given a title say - "Apple iPhone 5s (Space Grey, 16GB)"

I have to extract tokens from these titles and map to the dictionary values and assign appropriate keyword to each token.

Like for this - Brand - Apple, Color - Grey, Storage - 16GB

How should i tokenize these sentences? Doing it just by space will not be enough- like in this title - "Samsung Guru Music 2 SM-B310E (White)"
2 will be one token and can map to RAM,Display anything.

Will any NLP library help with this? I am using python to code and new to NLP.

```
    final_dict = {'Width': [81.28, 49.0], 'Brand': ['wd', 'lenovo', 'western digital'], 'Weight': [960.0], 'Height': [111.76, 109.22, 170.6]}
    map = {'Ram_gb' : ['gb','GB'],
           'Storage_gb' : ['gb','GB'],
           'FrontCamera' : ['MP','mp'],
           'BackCamera' : ['MP','mp'],
           'Display Resolution' : ['p','pixels'],
           'Weight' : ['gram','g','kg','Gram','KG'],
           'Generation' : ['gen','G','nd']
           }
    add_words = [""," ","-"]
    for key,value in self.final_dict.iteritems():
        if(key in map):
            adverb = map.get(key)
            new_dict = []
            for val in value:
                for ad in adverb:
                    for btw in add_words:
                        new_value = ""
                        new_value = str(val) + str(btw) + str(ad)
                        new_dict.append(new_value)
            self.final_dict[key].extend(new_dict)
            print self.final_dict[key]
```

This is the code for making all permutations of words possible in a title.

I have few titles -

```
apple macbook pro md101hn/a 13-inch laptop (core i5/4gb/500gb/intel hd graphics), silver;
lenovo g40-45 laptop(amd e1/ 2gb ram/ 500gb hdd/ win 8.1);
lenovo g40-80 notebook(4th gen- ci3/ 4gb ram/ 500gb hdd/ win 8.1) (black);
lenovo g50-80 notebook(5th gen- ci3/ 4gb ram/ 1tb hdd/ dos) (black);
dell inspiron 3542 notebook (4th gen- ci3/ 4gb ram/ 1tb hdd/ dos), silver;
```

How to extract data from these titles and map to the keys in dictionary.

Like for title one -

```
{
'Brand' : 'apple',
'processor' : 'core',
'RAM' : '4gb',
'color' : 'silver',
'Display' : '13-inch',
'Storage' : '500gb'
}
```

Comment: Please show us your code and what exactly you want to achieve. It is not really clear from the question and the example with the Samsung Guru Music is confusing it even more because it will *not* be one space-separated token.

Comment: You can use [nltk](http://www.nltk.org/). You can tokenize it using **nltk.download(sentence)**. Also, remember first to download the tokenizer using NLTK downloader: nltk.download('punkt'). After tokenize, read this [chapter](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html) and take a look at figure 1.1. You can follow the steps and finally get a list of tuples that establish relations between entities in your sentence.